# How to save rects from a for loop

Tags: android, rect

I've divide my screen up into rects, but I'm using a a for loop so I'm not storing the rects there getting remade each time. How would I store them in like an array?

```
     public void drawGrid() {
    //android.os.Debug.waitForDebugger();
    int height,width;
    int column,row;
    int maxColumn,maxRow;
    maxColumn = 4;
    maxRow = 4;
    column = 0;
    row = 0;
    height = c.getHeight()/maxRow;
    width = c.getWidth()/maxColumn;
    Paint pg = new Paint();
    Rect[] test[];


    for(int i = 0;i < 5; i++) {
        int srcX = column * width;
        int srcY = row * height;
        Rect src =new Rect(srcX,srcY,srcX + width, srcY +height);
        pg.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        pg.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        pg.setStrokeWidth(5);
        c.drawRect(src, pg);
        if (column == maxColumn && row == maxRow){
            i = 5;
        } else {i=0;}
        if (column == maxColumn){
            row = row + 1;
            column = 0;
        } else {column = column + 1;}

    }



}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Allocate them in advance, so that you're not instantiating objects during a drawing operation. So whenever you determine the number of rects that you'll need (i.e. if it's always the same, initialize them in the constructor). Something like this:

```
Rect[] rects = new Rect[rectCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rectCount; i++) rects[i] = new Rect();
```

Then, in your drawing loop, use:

```
rects[i].set(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
```

You should avoid allocating objects during a draw operation whenever possible.

EDIT: For a 2D array:

```
Rect[][] rects = new Rect[rowCount][colCount];
for(int i = 0; i < rowCount; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < colCount; j++) {
        rects[i][j] = new Rect();
    }
}
```

Then in the loop, it's the same thing:

```
rects[row][col].set(srcX, srcY, srcX + width, srcY + height);
```

Comment: I thought maybe it would better to do it that way. I want to set them in an array like rects[maxColumn][maxRow]. So that I can call them back by there coordinates in the grid. So when there made is just make it as Rect[Column][row]. Can I still do that that way?

Comment: Yeah, you can do that. Edited that in.

Answer (score 1):

```
Rect rectArray[] = new Rect[5];
```

Then inside the loop:

```
rectArray[i] = new Rect(srcX,srcY,srcX + width, srcY +height);
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you always going to have a fixed number of Rectangles?
You might want to consider an Array List?

```
ArrayList<Rect> rects = new ArrayList<Rect>();
rects.add(new Rect(srcX,srcY,srcX + width, srcY +height));
```

You can do loads of useful stuff easily with these things, here are some examples:
http://javarevisited.blogspot.com.es/2011/05/example-of-arraylist-in-java-tutorial.html

Comment: It's going to be determined by the maxRow and maxColumn. I thought maybe I could put them in an array like rectArray[maxRow][maxColumn]. And then call them back by there coordinates.